# Removing bottom borders for a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, border

I have a very simply problem which hopefully has a very simple solution. I am trying to create a macro to remove only the bottom borders of a range of cells. However, if I do something like

```
Range("D21:I28").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Linestyle = xlNone
```

It only removes the bottom border of the lowest row of cells. Is there a way to do this for each cell? I do not want to use a for loop because it's slow and you can see each individual cell's borders getting erased - I want to make it instantaneous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reconsider your decision and use a loop:

```
Sub UseALoop()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each r In Range("D21:I28")
        r.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Next r
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```