# Remove bottom borders from cell range in Excel 2016 VBA - not working?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range `sh.Range("F46:I46")` that currently has a thin bottom border that I want to get rid of using VBA, yet the solutions I've tried have failed to work. Right now all I have is:

```
sh.Range("F46:I46").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
```

I've also tried:

```
For Each r In sh.Range("F46:I46")
    r.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
Next r
```

...which is effectively the same thing, [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24803676/removing-bottom-borders-for-a-range-of-cells), and I've also tried:

```
sh.Range("F46:I46").Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone
```

...which I think is a VB.net code [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974965/how-to-remove-borders-from-cells-in-a-range-in-excel-using-vb-net).

Where am I going wrong????? Thanks!

Comment: Is it due to `F47:I47` have upper border? `Borders` is a child property of a cell, not vice versa.

Comment: It works for me. I hope it is not a line shape?

Comment: There is another possibility. The border is not of row 46 or of Row 47 but of 48 or some other row > 47. So imagine this. 47th row is hidden. 46th row has bottom border and 48th has top border. Your code will remove the bottom border of 46th row but you will still see the bottom border (which is actually top border of 48th row)

Comment: Other possibilities; cells are protected and an `on error resume next` is hiding it, or even `sh` that might point to a completely different sheet. So I guess it's better for you to post more code if this is part of a larger macro.

Comment: Curious, what happens when  you select a range that completely surrounds the cell and click`Normal` in the cell style gallery on the home tab?

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the suggestions, but I'm still having issues. The cells are not protected, and selecting a wider range to remove the border didn't do anything. I also ensured that sh is working with the current sheet only. @ProfoundlyOblivious When I check normal in the cell styles, is does go away! so maybe I could just use that in my macro?

Comment: Oh, I discovered the answer from the solutions provided. Thanks everyone! Will post momentarily...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what made it work. I just used:

```
sh.Range("F46:I48").Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
```

...without specifying `xlEdgeBottom` in the Borders function, and expanding the range a bit, so whatever "border" was being applied near my range was not of the xlEdgeBottom type. This command just removed them all.

Also, another solution that worked was just to apply a Normal cell style to the range in question, using:

```
sh.Range("F46:I48").Style = "Normal"
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Great follow-up. Congrats on your success.